# Non standard names - XPath

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, osb

I'm trying to get info from the tree of a web service message in OSB. But the name is non-standard (`<xml-fragment>`)

Here's the expression I'm using:

```
{$inputRoot_Res/PutResponse/ArrayOfInterfaceObjOutput/xml-fragment/idEntradaCaller/text()}
```

Well, seems that the data isn't being selected.

Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: `xml-fragment` is a perfectly valid element name; there's nothing wrong with it. You need to show more of your code.

Comment: Can you change the xml-generation? You're not dealing with valid XML: element names [may not start with "xml"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn). It doesn't seem to be disallowed for XPath engines handling these (at least I can't find anything against). I just tried using [BaseX](http://www.basex.org) and these names get handled totally fine (though highlighting seems strange). What engine are you using and please show more code.

Comment: Names beginning with "xml" are "reserved for future standardisation" but all tools I know of permit them, at most with a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems that I found the answer. I have a namespace in my structure that wasn't defined, and that's why I wasn't gathering data.

As Tomalak said, it's a valid name as it seems. So, the command ends like this:

{$inputRoot_Res/urn:PutResponse/ArrayOfInterfaceObjOutput/xml-fragment/idEntradaCaller/text()}

Where "urn" is defined in the namespaces box.

Sorry for the trouble, and thank you Tomalak and Jens Erat for your answers. =)